# import existing databricks user in terraform

Tags: terraform, databricks

Trying to import existing users by using Terraform import but getting an import error. The detailed log is as follows.

```html
terraform import databricks_user.user user@company.com
2022-01-23T12:28:18.894-0800 [INFO]  Terraform version: 1.1.4
2022-01-23T12:28:18.894-0800 [INFO]  Go runtime version: go1.17.6
2022-01-23T12:28:18.894-0800 [INFO]  CLI args: []string{"terraform", "import", "databricks_user.user", "user@company.com"}
2022-01-23T12:28:18.895-0800 [INFO]  CLI command args: []string{"import", "databricks_user.user", "user@company.com"}
2022-01-23T12:28:18.906-0800 [INFO]  Attempting to use session-derived credentials
2022-01-23T12:28:19.590-0800 [INFO]  Successfully derived credentials from session
2022-01-23T12:28:19.590-0800 [INFO]  AWS Auth provider used: "SSOProvider"
2022-01-23T12:28:21.940-0800 [INFO]  provider: configuring client automatic mTLS
2022-01-23T12:28:21.982-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v0.4.5: configuring server automatic mTLS: timestamp=2022-01-23T12:28:21.982-0800
2022-01-23T12:28:22.075-0800 [ERROR] AttachSchemaTransformer: No provider config schema available for provider["terraform.io/builtin/terraform"]
2022-01-23T12:28:22.075-0800 [INFO]  ReferenceTransformer: reference not found: "count.index"
2022-01-23T12:28:22.080-0800 [INFO]  provider: configuring client automatic mTLS
2022-01-23T12:28:22.117-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v0.4.5: configuring server automatic mTLS: timestamp=2022-01-23T12:28:22.117-0800
2022-01-23T12:28:22.209-0800 [WARN]  ValidateProviderConfig from "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/databrickslabs/databricks\"]" changed the config value, but that value is unused
2022-01-23T12:28:22.210-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v0.4.5: Explicit and implicit attributes: host, token: timestamp=2022-01-23T12:28:22.210-0800
databricks_user.user: Importing from ID "user@company.com"...
2022-01-23T12:28:22.212-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v0.4.5: Using directly configured PAT authentication: timestamp=2022-01-23T12:28:22.212-0800
2022-01-23T12:28:22.213-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v0.4.5: Configured pat auth: host=https://company.cloud.databricks.com, token=***REDACTED***: timestamp=2022-01-23T12:28:22.213-0800
2022-01-23T12:28:22.577-0800 [WARN]  provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v0.4.5: /api/2.0/preview/scim/v2/Users/user@company.com:405 - Endpoint not supported.: timestamp=2022-01-23T12:28:22.577-0800
2022-01-23T12:28:22.578-0800 [WARN]  provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v0.4.5: /api/2.0/preview/scim/v2/Users/user@company.com:405 - Endpoint not supported.: timestamp=2022-01-23T12:28:22.578-0800
databricks_user.user: Import prepared!
  Prepared databricks_user for import
databricks_user.user: Refreshing state... [id=user@company.com]
2022-01-23T12:28:22.832-0800 [WARN]  provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v0.4.5: /api/2.0/preview/scim/v2/Users/user@company.com:405 - Endpoint not supported.: timestamp=2022-01-23T12:28:22.832-0800
2022-01-23T12:28:22.833-0800 [WARN]  provider.terraform-provider-databricks_v0.4.5: /api/2.0/preview/scim/v2/Users/user@company.com:405 - Endpoint not supported.: timestamp=2022-01-23T12:28:22.832-0800
2022-01-23T12:28:22.837-0800 [ERROR] vertex "import databricks_user.user result" error: cannot read user: Endpoint not supported.
2022-01-23T12:28:22.837-0800 [ERROR] vertex "databricks_user.user (import id \"user@company.com\")" error: cannot read user: Endpoint not supported.
╷
│ Error: cannot read user: Endpoint not supported.
│ 
│ 
╵
```

Any suggestions what i am doing wrong?

Edit - Here is the corresponding terraform resource and provider block

```
resource "databricks_user" "user" {}
provider "databricks" {
  host  = "https://company.cloud.databricks.com"
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Comment: It would be good to see the code and not only the command.

Comment: original post updated with terraform resource and provider block

Comment: Is the user id the same thing as the user name? Documentation says the command to perform import is: `terraform import databricks_user.me <user-id>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Databricks provider documentation, the only required argument is the `user_name` [1]. So the block of code you are using to import the user:

```
resource "databricks_user" "user" {}
```

is not valid. Unfortunately, Terraform still does not create everything you need when importing the resources, so you have to provide the information. In your case that would be:

```
resource "databricks_user" "user" {
  user_name = "user@company.com"
}
```

In the documentation, the command to import the user is:

```
terraform import databricks_user.me <user-id>
```

Make sure to understand if the `<user-id>` is the same thing as the user name or you need to provide the ID instead. On their website [2], I can see this:

```
<user-id> with the Databricks workspace ID of the user, for example 2345678901234567. To get the user ID, call Get users.
```

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/user

[2] https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/scim/scim-users.html#get-users

Comment: Thank you very much. That was it. I was passing the user name to terraform import under the impression that it was the user id but your answer was spot on. I appreciate the help

Comment: Databricks provider includes exporter functionality that generates both HCL & import script: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/guides/experimental-exporter. Also, latest version supports `force` flag for users & groups to automatically import them if they already exist in workspace